# Encrypting and opening an encrypted SQLite database in C# using System.Data.SQLite after password-protection methods removal

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, encryption, ado

We have updated our `System.Data.SQLite` NuGet packages to version 1.0.113.0 which no longer seem to support encryption out of the box; `SQLiteConnection.SetPassword()` and `SQLiteConnection.ChangePassword()`, as well as support for the `Password` field in `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` are gone. What can be done to encrypt and open an encrypted database now?